# Trouble embedding a .mov video

Tags: video-streaming

Tried this with Meteor, Chrome:

```
<object CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="sample.mov">
    <param name="qtsrc" value="rtsp:/videos/my video.mov">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="loop" value="false">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <embed src="sample.mov" qtsrc="rtsp://videos/v.mov"
           width="320" height="256" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true"
           pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/">
```

That, on Chrome, complains that a plug-in needs to be installed.

Also tried this:

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
            src="/videos/my.mov"
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

That results in a file being downloaded, not streamed (the "Save as" dialog appears)

Also, I am getting this on my standard output:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/quicktime: "http://localhost:3000/videos/MX_pricing_video_6.18.2015.mov".
```

I suspect something is wrong with my mime types. I vaguely recall you set up mime types in Apache settings; how do you do that on Meteor/Node?

How do I embed this video into the page?

Edit.

Not a duplicate. I've read  and tried [How to embed a .mov file in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521849/how-to-embed-a-mov-file-in-html) before asking the question. I've tried everything.

I should have posted it, but

```
  <video controls="controls" width="800" height="600" name="Video Name" src="/videos/my.mov"></video>
```

Displays the all black video control, but the "play" button does not do anything. No messages in console either.

The one below, like I said, says plug-in not supported. Shows a puzzle icon.

```
<object CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="sample.mov">
    <param name="qtsrc" value="rtsp://realmedia.uic.edu/itl/ecampb5/demo_broad.mov">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="loop" value="false">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <embed src="sample.mov" qtsrc="rtsp://realmedia.uic.edu/itl/ecampb5/demo_broad.mov" width="320" height="256" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/"></embed>
</object>
```

Also, event though someone had edited away Meteor, I do think it has something to do with Node if not Meteor, because somewhere mime types need to be set properly, no? I remember doing it on Apache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed a .mov file in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521849/how-to-embed-a-mov-file-in-html)

Comment: where in your project folder do you store the video?

Comment: @ChristianFritz in /public/videos

Answer (score 0):

Just store your `my.mov` file in your `/public/videos` folder in your meteor project directory. Afterwards, the following works (no need to manually set the mime type anywhere):

```
<video controls="controls" width="800" height="600" 
       name="Video Name" src="/videos/my.mov">
</video>
```

Here is what I did:

```
$ meteor create test
$ cd test 
$ mkdir -p public/videos
$ cp SOMEVIDEO.mov public/videos
$ ## edit test.html to add the above snippet into the body
```

Run `meteor` and go to `localhost:3000`. The video shows up (using Chrome 43 on OSX).

Comment: IE: Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path

Comment: Chrome: black screen with dead controls

Comment: Firefox: video format or MIME format is not supported.

Comment: I am thinking my video format might be different from yours, even though they are both .mov. I can't share mind, would you mind sharing yours?

Comment: I just used a .mov file I found preinstalled on my mac of the Eiffel Tower. The extension doesn't mean much. Perhaps just post the details of the codec.

Comment: How? Perhaps you could share the file? Maybe drop it in Dropbox?