# any video player (jquery etc) to embed .mov file in html page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, html5-video

i am developing an MVC 4 web application and i need to support playing video files of various formats. i.e. User can upload videos files of multiple formats and website shall support those formats. I am having difficulty play .mov files. I have seen the following links already but they dont work for me. I think, these are older links and not working for me, perhaps embed & object tags have compatibility issues in later/newer browsers
[How to embed a .mov file in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521849/how-to-embed-a-mov-file-in-html/18994322)
http://jquery.malsup.com/media/

can anybody help me please ?

Comment: i need this .mov video playing support in firefox, chrome, IE, safari. Also need video playing support of various video formats

Comment: If I'm no wrong you can't do it using HTML5 standards at present time. If your target clients are using a unique combination of OS + Browser maybe you could apply a solution like that you link.

Comment: As mov containers aren't generally supported in the browser without the Quicktime plugin, you will need to transcode the uploaded video on server side (see f.ex. ffmpeg) and present the transcoded video for preview/playback and the original for download (depending on your scenario).